# How to get particular var/constant value through promise in javascript

Tags: javascript, promise, response

I am trying to retrieve statelist variable value, using promise.
I am using streamlit_javascript (python library) to run the promise.

In javascript of the below shown URL, has the statelist variable. I need to retrive that using the response function.
Below code shows my response function. Its showing an error, statelist not defined.

```
return_value = st_javascript("""await fetch("http://localhost:8501").then(function(response){

console.log("Success!", response);

return response.json($statelist); });""")
```

Here is the code of the variable, what I need to retrive.

```
var statelist = new Set()
statelist.add('Kansas')
```

Comment: What are these `"""` blocks? Are you running JS code from Python? You provided no context for us to help you with that.

Comment: Edited the question, issue is not with the python library. So, didnt added that information.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use python's `requests`?

In javascript, response.json() also returns a promise so you'll need another `.then()` like this:

```
fetch("https:url-here").then(res => res.json()).then(json => json)
```